# Regex test not passing

Tags: javascript, regex

The value I am testing with is: `prefixa:rxcj7sdek1n7mbybiibxr4w09w`

`hasValidFormat` keeps returning false when I expect it to return true.

```
export function isValidValue(value: unknown): value is Value {
  if (typeof value !== 'string') {
    return false;
  }

  const validPrefixes = Object.values(ValidPrefix);
  
  const hasValidPrefix = validPrefixes.some(prefix => value.startsWith(prefix));
  const hasValidFormat = /^[\w]+:[0-9a-f]{26}$/.test(value);

  // Add console logs for debugging
  console.log('the value is:', value);
  console.log('hasValidPrefix:', hasValidPrefix);
  console.log('hasValidFormat:', hasValidFormat);

  return hasValidPrefix && hasValidFormat;
}

// Valid Prefix
export enum ValidPrefix {
  PREFIXA = 'prefixa',
  PREFIXB = 'prefixa'
}
```

Comment: `[0-9a-f]{26}` won't match `rxcj7sdek1n7mbybiibxr4w09w`. You need to include letters from `a-z`.

Comment: You apparently copied a regexp that was designed to only match hexadecimal numbers, not any letter. Don't just copy blindly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are limiting the regex to allow only the characters a,b,c,d,e and f.
The value you are evaluating contains letters greater than f, it should be:

```
/^[\w]+:[0-9a-z]{26}$/
```